# How can i create a my own custom button without using interface builder?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsobject

I want to create my own custom button without using any interface builder.

Actually i wants to set all my properties/attribute(Like frame,color,size,label etc.) separate in a NSObject class.Then from my UIView class i want to draw them .

How can i do it as i am never use NSObject class?

Any sample application or example to do this?

Comment: If you want to create a custom button you should at least inherit from `UIView` (if you don't wish to inherit from `UIButton` directly). Making it a (direct) subclass of `NSObject` will just complicate things.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can subclass `UIButton` - for an example, have a look at [Fun With UIButtons and Core Animation Layers](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/). Is this is too much, you can simply create a new `UIButton` and set it's properties:

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame]
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
...
[btn release;]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this Code:

```
    UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(152,0,150,128)];       
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btn setImage:actualImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
    [btn setTag:1];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTouched:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addSubview:btn];
    [btn release];
```

Comment: you should clean up your code in order to avoid confusion, e.g. there is no `i` declared, you are adding btn as a subview to btn, there is no `copyOf_myGlobalArrayOfImageIds` and you should add `[btn release];` at the end of your code.

Comment: you're over releasing it now :) (you autorelease it in the first line and release it again in the last line)

Comment: Now it's fine i though :) thanks @babbidi